# Difference between Database.executeBatch vs System.scheduleBatch

Tags: apex, batch, database

I am curious to know is there any notable difference between `Database.executeBatch` vs `System.scheduleBatch`. One difference I know is, we can delay the batch execution in **scheduleBatch** method. However, I did not find any **performance** related documents.

Anyone have experienced any performance difference with these methods?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The performance of all Batch Apex (all asynchronous Apex, really) can vary based on system load. That applies regardless of whether the batch is enqueued immediately or with a time delay, based on the load when execution actually happens.

The extra wrinkle with `System.scheduleBatch()` is that [scheduled job limits apply at the time of scheduling](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm#:%7E:text=Apex%20Scheduler%20Limits), while normal batch Apex limits are applied once the schedule fires and enqueues the batch job:

> All scheduled Apex limits apply for batch jobs scheduled using `System.scheduleBatch`. After the batch job is queued (with a status of Holding or Queued), all batch job limits apply and the job no longer counts toward scheduled Apex limits.

You also don't have to implement `Schedulable` in your batch class if you're only using one-off scheduling with `System.scheduleBatch()`.

Comment: Thanks David! Which one you'd recommend to use,?

Comment: Use `Database.executeBatch()` unless you specifically need to delay the execution of the batch class. I never use `System.scheduleBatch()` myself.